# How to explain to a five year old why certain words are spelled this way

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonetics, letter-writing, sounds, spelling-pronunciations

My five-year-old is learning phonics. I give him spelling test time to time. I asked him to spell "`Hair`" and he spelled it as "`Her`" & then I told him this is incorrect spelling. He then wrote "`Hur`". This is just one example and I keep running into these issues everyday.

I know the spellings of words, but in some cases I don't know why they are spelled this way.

What is the best way to explain kids why certain spelling is correct and certain spelling even though it may sound correct is wrong spelling.

Can I use any website, app or tool to explain the logic behind spellings\sounds. I am happy to buy paid subscription as well.

Are there any books that are highly recommended for 5-7 year old when they are learning phonics ?

Comment: Why do you believe that there is any _logic_ behind spellings\sounds?

Comment: `I think` (& I can be wrong) most words (except the sight words) have logic. Assuming there is no logic, what do we tell the kids? The way we learned words 20 years ago was a lot different. I am trying to find the best way to deal with this. Thanks !!

Comment: Spelling tests are passe until 2nd grade, as any reasonably phonetic, good-guess spelling is plenty. Best you could do is explain *convention*. We drive on this side of the road because it's safe if we all do that, not because right or left is better.

Comment: Because your grampa couldn't spell very well, and he got to write the first spelling book.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I am not worried about kid passing test at this stage. I am happy with `good-guess spelling` capability as well. I just wanted to learn if there is a way to explain why you spell a word in specific manner. Can you please give me examples of conventions you use. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where in the world? I can think of one place where *hair* is actually pronounced like *hur.*

Comment: The question applies to all words, not only to those mentioned. There are many answers, each relevant to the word to be considered. The choice of word to consider is a matter of opinion and so, as the comments demonstrate, is any specific, or general, answer. I therefore vote to close, the answer being a matter of opinion.

Comment: There's a reason spelling was pushed from Kindergarten to 2nd grade. It's not intuitive or easy, and it requires memorization. The answer "this words has its root in Greek, so it's spelled differently than this similar word we borrowed from French" isn't going to be easier. Knowing how to spell a lot of words first would help someone develop a sense of the patterns that loosely apply.

Comment: An example of convention is driving on the right. We are safe if we all do it even though all on the left is the standard in other places. By convention.

Comment: Get this book: https://www.amazon.com/English-Pronunciation-Illustrated-John-Trim/dp/0521206340 You can adapt the a sounds for American English. It will give you all the phonemic combinations in pairs. It is very funny and you can have fun explaining the pictures he doesn't get. It will also help you understand that sounds can be materialized in several ways.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it's off-topic because it's asking for recommendations rather than factual answers. Questions about resources are normally posted on meta.